# How to mass update many to many related tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-update, many-to-many

I am fetching data from an external API and I want to `insert` or update those data to two tables with many to many relationship using Laravel and MySQL.

Table Structure

Orders Table

```
|id (Auto Increment /Not related to API) | order_id (from API) | some other columns |
```

Products Table

```
|id (Auto Increment /Not related to API) | product_id (from API) | some other columns |
```

Orders_Products Table

```
|order_id (FK) | product_id (FK) | quantity (int) | some other columns |
```

Here's the data structure of the response from the API.

```
orders : [
    order_id : 1234568586,
    some_fields : abcd,
    products : [
         {
             product_id : 14578546,
             quantity : 10,
             some_fields
         },
         {
             product_id : 24578546,
             quantity : 5,
             some_fields
         }
    ]
]
```

**What I require to do**

I want to `insert` or `updateIfExist` all these orders (into Orders Table) with their products (into Products table) and map the relationships (into Orders_Product Table).

**My Approach**

```
foreach (orders as order) {
    //insert/update Order and keep its id

    foreach(order->products as product){
        //fetch Product Model if it product_id already exists
        //else make a new Product Model.

        //insert/update Product
        //add relationship
   }
}
```

**My Question**

My approach works fine. I can insert/update all the necessary data to the database. **But** I am pretty sure this is very inefficient because the database is queried many times. So if there are like 1000 orders, this code will take a long time to execute.
**I would appreciate it enormously if you could mention an efficient way to do this.**

Comment: You could use the [`upsert()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#upserts) method for this kind of operations. Just adapt it to work for your case.

Comment: Can upsert() be used to work with several tables? As I understood, upsert can be used with one table. Could you please give me an example if it's possible?

Comment: Yes but you will end up doing just 2 queries per order: One for  `orders` table and one more for `order_products` (which will upsert all the order products at once). This way, your complexity will get reduced to only orders*2

Comment: ```foreach(orders as order) { order->update; upsert() } ```

Comment: Is this what you meant? I'm sorry I can't understand it. First I loop through orders and get an ```order```. In here, I can upsert all the products. But how do I add the relationships in order_products?

Comment: You could manually insert the values in your table: `$order_products =[['order_id' => $orderId, $productId, $quantity, ...], ...]` and then upsert in your table: `DB::table('order_products')->upsert(...);`

Comment: But for this to work, I need $productId s from the database. (```product_id``` in API corresponds to column ```products.product_id```. But in order to upsert as you mentioned, I have to upsert the products first and get their ```id```s somehow. Then I can use upsert in ```orders_products``` table. But how do I get those product ids?

Comment: But you should already have the product ids, otherwise how will you link them to the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many product you have in your table, you could retrieve them all in an array, indexed with there ID.

This will allow you to avoid multiple database request each time.

```
// $products = [
//     1 => $product1,
//     2 => $product2,
//     ...
//     ];
$products = getAllMyProductsIndexedById();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    //insert/update Order and keep its id

    foreach($order->products as $product){
        //fetch Product Model if it product_id already exists
        if(array_key_exists(product->id, $products){
            $productEntity = $products[product->id];
        } else {
            //else make a new Product Model.
            // and add it to the array $products
        }

        //insert/update Product
        //add relationship
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary tables of the data structures from the API, and the do the laravel version of `insert into orders select ... from orders_tmp ... on duplicate key update ...` (and the same for products).

ref: [MariaDB insert](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/) / [MySQL insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible. But products are coming as a property of order in the API response. So I have to map the relationships with the id values that are auto incremented

Comment: Are you saying that order_id and product_id aren't unique? Can these be combined with an API source_id to form a unique key (or primary key replacing the auto increments current PK)? Declaring unique keys can work with IODKU just as well as PK.

Comment: order_id and product_id are unique. As you mention here, how do I add the necessary relationships in Orders_Products table? For that I need the PK. If I use IODKU with unique keys, it will update but how do I get the PKs to add relationship?

Comment: Good question. I'd hope `Orders_Products`, `order_id` and `product_id` map to the API id. Is `(order_id, product_id)` combined a unique element (i.e. an order cannot have the same product twice)? If so this can be a combined PK or combined unique key. I'm hoping @Kenny Horna will give a more complete upsert answer.

Comment: Yes order_id and product_id combined is a unique element. Could you please give me an example. I'm unable to grasp your explanation